# character ö with gfsartemisia-euler

Tags: fonts, errors, accents

I am using gfsartemisia-euler and I would like to use ö but intead I get something strange.
MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={165mm, 240mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{setspace}
        \usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{frcursive}
        \usepackage{calligra}
        \usepackage{csquotes}
        \usepackage{titlesec}
        \usepackage{tocloft}
        \usepackage{color}
        \usepackage[draft]{listofsymbols}
        \usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
        \usepackage{bm}
        \usepackage{textcomp}
        \usepackage{upgreek}


        \usepackage{translator}


        \begin{document}
test höla
I also try H\"ola 
        \end{document}
```

[image]
Thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, the font fails to set the correct diereses (Umlaute) not only for `ö` but also for `ä`, `ü`, `Ä`, `Ö`, and `Ü`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the loading of the packages to a more common order seems to get it right.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={165mm, 240mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[draft]{listofsymbols}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{translator}

\begin{document}
    test höla
    I also try H\"ola 
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: If one comments out the instruction`\usepackage{tipa}` from your code, one once again gets the OP's screenshot. This raises the question whether `tipa` somehow "fixes" `gfsartemisia-euler` or if the diereses produced by your ordering of the packages are actually the ones produced by `tipa`.

Comment: It seemed `tipa` was fixing the encoding. I edited the MWE. @Mico

Answer (score 3):

For very mysterious reasons, the `gfsartemisia-euler` package has the line

```
\@ifpackagewith{fontenc}{T1}{}{\def\"#1{\accent168#1}}
```

which is a ***very silly*** thing to do (I could use stronger words), because the font has `ĺ` at that position.

However, if you change the loading order to

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={165mm, 240mm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler} %%% before fontenc!

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}

\begin{document}

test höla
I also try H\"ola

\end{document}
```

the silly line has no effect.

[image]