# \acute accent in math mode gfsartemisia-euler

Tags: math-mode, fonts, euler

I want to  use `\acute` accent in mathmode but I get a wrong output in pdf file. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={160mm, 240mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
    \usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{calligra}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}



\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{upgreek}


\begin{document}

$\acute{a}$


\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure your example is minimal ...

Comment: The problem seems to come from `\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}`

Comment: Sorry for the long preamble but I am not sure where the problem may come from. is there a way to include accents using '\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}'?

Comment: Maybe this can help : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319439/character-%C3%B6-with-gfsartemisia-euler

Comment: The way to make the example "minimal" is to start stripping out stuff from the preamble to see if the problem persists.  Once you have taken out all that can be removed while the problem remains, *then* the example is "minimal"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

$\acute{a}$

\end{document}
```

The loading order of your packages is wrong: the `gfsartemisia-euler` package should be called after `fontenc`.

Solution for your (not minimal) example, with some *important* changes. Please, read the changed file carefully; most relevant is having tidied the source. Note that the package `epsfig` is obsolete and should never used in newer document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,12pt]{book}

%% pagination
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  total={160mm, 240mm},
  headheight=20pt,
  heightrounded,
]{geometry}

%% general settings
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}

%% fonts
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bm}

%% other packages
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[]{appendix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage[texindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
  bibencoding=ascii,
  style=chem-angew,
  citestyle=numeric-comp,
  sorting=none,
]{biblatex}

%% fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
}
\fancypagestyle{chapterfirstpage}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\patchcmd{\chapter}
  {\thispagestyle{plain}}
  {\thispagestyle{chapterfirstpage}}
  {\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed}\rule[0pt]{\textwidth}{1pt}}

%% biblatex
\addbibresource{biblio} 
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \lhead[Bibliografía]{}%
  \rhead[]{Bibliografía}%
}

%% epigraph
%\renewcommand{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{1\textwidth}
%\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}
\renewcommand{\sourceflush}{flushepinormal}

%% graphicx
\graphicspath{{./figuras/}}

%% xcolor
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.9}

%% titlesec
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge}{\thechapter.}{0.1em}{\Huge}

%% tocloft
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnum{.}

%% personal commands
\newcommand\blankpage{%
  \null
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
  \newpage
}

%% final settings
\makeindex
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} % para que ponga 1.1.1.1..
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3} % para que añadir las secciones en el índice...
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

$\acute{a}$

\end{document}
```